# Combine two rows in Pandas depending on values in a column and creating a new category

Tags: python, pandas

I am most interested in how this is done in a good and excellent pandas way.

In this example data `Tim` from `Osaka` has two `fruit`'s.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['Susan', 'Tim', 'Tim', 'Anna'],
        'fruit': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana'],
        'town': ['Berlin', 'Osaka', 'Osaka', 'Singabpur']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Result

```
    name   fruit       town
0  Susan   Apple     Berlin
1    Tim   Apple      Osaka
2    Tim  Banana      Osaka
3   Anna  Banana  Singabpur
```

I investigate the data ans see that one of the persons have multiple fruits. I want to create a new "category" for it named `banana&fruit` (or something else). The point is that the other fields of `Tim` are equal in their values.

```
df.groupby(['name', 'town', 'fruit']).size()
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to explore this data set. The logical question behind is if some of the person+town combinations have multiple fruits.

As a result I want this

```
    name   fruit             town
0  Susan   Apple             Berlin
1    Tim   Apple&Banana      Osaka
2   Anna   Banana            Singabpur
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby(['name', 'town'], as_index=False, sort=False)
        .agg(fruit=('fruit', '&'.join))
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    name       town         fruit
0  Susan     Berlin         Apple
1    Tim      Osaka  Apple&Banana
2   Anna  Singabpur        Banana
```

Comment: I always forgot `sort=False` and gg for your TOP10 this month! +1

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df.groupby(["name", "town"], sort=False)["fruit"]
      .apply(lambda f: "&".join(f)).reset_index()

    name       town         fruit
0   Anna  Singabpur        Banana
1  Susan     Berlin         Apple
2    Tim      Osaka  Apple&Banana
```